# Reflow and resize inAppBrowser HTML in Ionic/Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm testing the inAppBrowser plugin in Ionic (which uses Cordova) and the HTML appears very small in the emulator screen. When I test the same code in a separate browser within the emulator the text is much larger and more legible. Here's the code to open the site within inAppBrowser:

```
    var options = {
        location: 'yes',
        clearcache: 'yes',
        toolbar: 'no'
      };

$cordovaInAppBrowser.open("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1288776/000128877615000035/goog10-qq22015.htm", '_blank', options)
        .then(function(event) {
          // success
        })
        .catch(function(event) {
          // error
        });
```

If I change `_blank` to `_system` a separate browser opens the HTML page better sized to fit the screen. But I'd like to see similarly sized text within the inAppBrowser.

How do I get the text to appear larger within the inAppBrowser window? Maybe some equivalent of the viewport meta tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injecting a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) via the executeScript function appears to have (at least on my test page) worked. The text is larger, more legible and the bulk of the text fits the width of the screen.

```
    var options = {
        location: 'yes',
        clearcache: 'yes',
        toolbar: 'no'
      };

      var script = 
      "var meta = document.createElement('meta');"+
      "meta.name = 'viewport';"+
      "meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no';"+
      "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

      //$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(cordova.file.dataDirectory + "Documents/" + "sec.html", '_blank', options)
      $cordovaInAppBrowser.open("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1288776/000128877615000035/goog10-qq22015.htm", '_self', options)
        .then(function(event) {
          // success
          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){
            $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript({
              code: script
            });
          });
        })
        .catch(function(event) {
          // error
        });
```

You'll notice the meta tag is similar to the one you're likely have on your Ionic/Cordova index.html page. But this doesn't seem to be inherited by inAppBrowser so I've injected it after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InAppBrowsers "insertCSS" function to add CSS to the InAppBrowser's browser view, as documented [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).

For example something like:

```
iab.insertCSS({ code: "p { background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff; }" });
```

Then add the CSS you want to adjust relative sizes of page elements.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this is you'd need to predetermine what website's the user is likely to visit through inAppBrowser and alter the sizing of all the CSS elements for each site. I think your method works best when you know what website the user is accessing and there are not many elements that need resizing.

Comment: You could try some sort of meta tag injection too as you suggest, I've successfully used the above technique when dropping out to pages that I know don't change much (FAQs etc).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in case injecting the meta tag doesn't work for other sites I test. Thanks for the help.